# Fatal error: Call to a member function getType() on a non-object in /plugins/system/sef/sef.php on line 38

Tags: joomla-3.x, sef, sh404sef

I get this error instead of the classical page not found when the url is wrong:
Fatal error: Call to a member function getType() on a non-object in /plugins/system/sef/sef.php on line 38

Scenario:
LAMP - Centos6 + Plesk 11.5
Joomla! 3.5.1 Stable [ Unicorn ] 05-April-2016 22:45 GMT
SH404
CB
ohanah

any tips?

Comment: I think you should contact sh404sef

Answer (score 1):

Have you recently updated Joomla to Joomla 3.5.1? This error is typically caused by a botched update (see: http://www.itoctopus.com/resolving-the-dreaded-call-to-a-member-function-getdocument-on-a-non-object-error-on-a-joomla-website )

I think you have some folders from your old Joomla installation that are causing this problem. Deleting these folders will fix the problem.